# Auctex in 12.04 ignores Emacs 24

Tags: emacs

I just installed Emacs 24 (emacs24 24.1+1-2ubuntu3) in Ubuntu 12.04 but it does not seem to work with Auctex (the current version is 11.86-2ubuntu2). My .emacs file contains a line loading Auctex, so when starting the editor for the first time I received an error it cannot find auctex.el. Indeed /usr/share/emacs/24.1/site-lisp does not contain any trace of auctex. I thought it could be an issue with auctex being installed before emacs 24, so I reinstalled it. The installation log reads as follows:

```
Setting up auctex (11.86-2ubuntu2) ...
Install auctex for emacs
Install auctex for emacs23
install/auctex: Setting up for emacs23 (log file: /usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/auctex//CompilationLog)... done.
update-auctex-elisp[20829]: Further output will appear in: /var/log/auctex-emacs23.log.
Install auctex for emacs24
install/auctex: Ignoring emacsen flavor: "emacs24".
```

Is the current version of auctex incompatible with emacs24? Alternatively, is there a way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 5):

As a workaround, you may install AucTeX locally from the [Emacs Lisp Package Archive (ELPA)](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA):

`M-x package-install auctex`

Answer (score 5):

You need to edit the file

/usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/auctex

At the end of the file, look for this chunk:

```
    case "${FLAVOR}" in
       emacs) :;;
       emacs2[123]|emacs-snapshot)
              do_clean_old_cruft ${FLAVOR}
         do_install ${FLAVOR}
              do_auto ${FLAVOR};;
       *) echo >&2 "install/auctex:" \
           "Ignoring emacsen flavor: \"${FLAVOR}\"."
    esac
```

Change "123" to "1234" and then sudo dpkg-reconfigure auctex.

I stumbled across this online. I wish I could give credit but have forgotten the source.

Comment: Here's the source: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=683032

Comment: This does not work in ubuntu 13.10

Comment: I believe that Ubuntu 13.10 correctly installs auctex and it appears to only support emacs 23 and 24. Did you sudo apt-get install auctex?

Comment: I just realized that it happens only if there is a empty line in the local variables list (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/auctex/+bug/1149196)